# Spark generate Sub Dataframes from a super Dataframe Optimized approach

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

This is the input Spark dataframe . Based on the "Code type" I need to split this dataframe into sub dataframes, as below

```
val dsTotal = fr.toDF("Key","Code")
dsTotal.show()
```

```
--------------
|key  | Code |
--------------
|200  | DS   |
|300  | CP   |
|400  | DS   |
|76   | OR   |
|45   | CP   |
|34   | DS   |
|33   | OR   |
|200  | DS   |
--------------
```

I have used filter option repeatedly on the same super dataframe  to create a sub dataframes . Is there any other better approach to generate the sub dataframes

```
val ds1 = dsTotal.filter(col("Code").equalTo("CP"))
ds1.show()
```

```
--------------
|key  | Code |
--------------
|45   | CP   |
|300  | CP   |
--------------

val ds2 = dsTotal.filter(col("Code").equalTo("DS"))
ds2.show()
```

```
--------------
|key  | Code |
--------------
|200  | DS   |
|400  | DS   |
|200  | DS   |
|34   | DS   |
--------------

val ds3 = dsTotal.filter(col("Code").equalTo("OR"))
ds3.show()
--------------
|key  | Code |
--------------
|76   | OR   |
|33   | OR   |
--------------
```

Comment: What are you going to do next with your dataframes? If you just need to save, use `partitionBy` on DataFrameWriter. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42645836/split-dataset-based-on-column-values-in-spark for details.

Comment: I just want to split a dataframe into sub dataframes .so that i can use those sub dataframes in my subsequent coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filter` and `select` are among the best approach I've seen to `split` a `dataframe` to `subdataframe`s.

So you have one of the best approach but your `filter` has static check of `Code`, which can be avoided by doing the following.

First step is to get the `distinct` values of `Code` column

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val array = df.select(collect_list("Code")).first()(0).asInstanceOf[mutable.WrappedArray[String]].distinct
```

which should give you

```
WrappedArray(DS, CP, OR)
```

Next step would be to loop through the `distinct` values and store the `subdataframe`s in a `hashmap`

```
val splittedDFs : mutable.HashMap[String, DataFrame] = mutable.HashMap.empty[String, DataFrame]
for(key <- array){
  splittedDFs ++= mutable.HashMap(key -> df.filter($"Code" === key))
}
```

now you can access the sub-dataframe

```
splittedDFs("CP").show(false)
```

which should be

```
+---+----+
|key|Code|
+---+----+
|300|CP  |
|45 |CP  |
+---+----+
```

You can use `select` instead of `filter` too.

I hope the answer is helpful